# Vue 3: How to get boolean data from parent (using <script setup>) into child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Firstly, I know this is probably a SUPER easy question, but I've been struggling for an hour and half and I'm kinda done with that. First vue project ever, so I've never had 2 components talk to each other, let alone when `<script setup>` is involved.

Any relevant docs that help me understand WHY this works this way would be wonderful. I want to learn how this works, but my google searching is getting me nowhere.

This app is simple, its just toggling light mode and dark mode on some cards. There's more to it than what's below, but I've stripped away the irrelevant (working) code for ease of reading.

My App.vue code:

```html
<script setup>
import {ref, defineProps} from "vue";
import card from './components/card.vue'

const darkMode = ref(false);

const props = defineProps({
  darkMode: Boolean
})
</script>

<template>
// Bunch of stuff that is irrelevant to the scope of this problem, it works just fine. 
</template>
```

My card.vue code:

```html
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1 :class="{ 'text-white': darkMode }"> Content! </h1>
</template>
```

There's more complexity to the project, but all I'm trying to do right now is get them to talk. I just want the class to be added based on whether `darkMode` is `true` or `false` in the parent.

Comment: "irrelevant to the scope of this problem" - is it? card.vue isn't used anywhere. Did you try to do this without `script setup` syntax? What is the code? There's a clear connection between options api, composition api using `script`, and composition api using `script setup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the `card.vue` component to receive `darkMode`, it needs to have a prop (via [`defineProps`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) in `<script setup>` or the [`props` option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props) in `<script>`). However, you've declared the `darkMode` prop in `App.vue` when it actually needs to be in `card.vue`. Also note there's no need to import `defineProps`, as it's a compiler macro that automatically gets replaced by the compiler:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import card from './components/card.vue'

const darkMode = ref(false);

// ❌ move this to card.vue
//const props = defineProps({
//  darkMode: Boolean
//})
</script>
```

```html
<!-- card.vue -->
<script setup>
// ✅ card.vue can now receive `darkMode` from parent
const props = defineProps({
  darkMode: Boolean
})
</script>
```

Then, use the [`v-bind` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) to bind the value of `App.vue`'s `darkMode` ref to `card.vue`'s `darkMode` prop:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <card :darkMode="darkMode" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-child-prop?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fcard.vue)